# Outlook interop causes outlook to stall *after* event handler has finished

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I'm having an issue where if my application is busy/unresponsive/paused for a breakpoint, it causes outlook to stall even though my mail received event handler has long since returned.

I've put together a small test case:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace OutlookPerfTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Application app;
        private static NameSpace ns;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type olType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application", false);

            app = Activator.CreateInstance(olType) as Application;
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);

            app.NewMailEx += app_NewMailEx;

            for (; ; )
            { Thread.Sleep(10000); }
        }

        static void app_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New mail event triggered, running on background worker...");
            var bg = new BackgroundWorker();
            bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
            bg.RunWorkerAsync(EntryIDCollection);
            Console.WriteLine("New mail event ended, returning");
        }

        static void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("New mail thread started");

            string EntryIDCollection = (string)e.Argument;

            foreach (var id in EntryIDCollection.Split(','))
            {
                if (ns.GetItemFromID(id) is MailItem)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(id + " is a mail item");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("New mail thread Ended");
        }
    }
}
```

During the `Thread.Sleep(5000);` outlook remains happy and responsive. By the time the following `Console.WriteLine` is called, the original `app_NewMailEx` event handler has long since returned.

However if I breakpoint on that line, or otherwise lock my application up doing some intensive task - outlooks remains unresponsive during that time even though the event isn't being re-fired.

If I remove the event handler when the message arrives, and re-add it again once I've finished `bg_DoWork` then it alleviates the problem - but this means messages will be missed if they arrive between those two times.

Why does this happen? And how can I stop outlook from becoming unresponsive in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a command line app, it does not run the Windows message pump used by COM.
Do yo usee teh same problem in a GUI app?

Comment: Yes. The command line app was just put together as a test case. The WPF application we're working on has exactly the same issue.

Comment: What is your code? Are you also using secondary threads/background workers?